# Why is url_for returning /assets for undefined routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm upgrading from rails 3.1.3 to 3.2.2, but for some reason now url_for always returns /assets if the route doesn't exist.

For example:

```
url_for({}) #=> "/assets"
url_for({action: 'fake', controller: 'notreal'}) #=> /assets?action=fake&controller=notreal
```

But I want it to to throw the normal ActionController::RoutingError as it normally does...

Comment: Strange one. Check all your env configs. Did you redefine `url_for`? Did you run `rake rails:update`?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem here. For the simplest Scenario, ie. No resource, just created a DemoController and used redirect_to :action => 'show' from the index action. and it generates that type of URL: /assets?action=show&controller=demo
I'd expect this to render the show template. Did you find out what's going on?

Comment: @user766388 still a mystery :/

Comment: I did notice that rails 3.2 is using Journey engine for routing now, so I suspect it is related to, or a combination of, some old config setting(s) from 3.0/1 and the new routing engine.

Comment: Good point, definitely something to do with the recent changes to the framework. Unfortunately I noticed that now rails forces you to create a route in order to trigger this type of actions. And more unfortunate.. I don't think this is even a bug, but puzzling nonetheless because it contradicts what I've read in the Book the "Rails 3 Way", which of course is based on the early versions of rails 3.

Comment: @bkempner: Did you solve this? Did the answer below help? Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does not check for route existence if you build up the route via specifying controller-action. And naturally it shows /assets for {} route.

You should better specify named routes in routes.rb and then use them for url_for. Like:

**url_for add_user_path**

This ensures you will either succeed (for existent named route) or get an error.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think you have assets pre-compilation on and since the image does not exist in the assets folder, the compile file name is null but the path points to the root of the assets folder.  Are you also be seeing an error about not finding the pre-compiled asset in the logs?

Try running without assets pre-compilation in the development environment to get past this. I will not rehash details on assets precompilation - you can check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for details on asset pipeline.  If you are seeing this issue only in production environment, it might be because the host platform is precompiling the assets for you.

However, if you expect this to happen in production, you might want to check for the presence of the image instead of disabling precompilation.